# Creating Shared Looker Studio Reports from Templates and Managing Access with Linking API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, puppeteer, looker-studio

I'm currently using the Linking API from Looker Studio, but I have a specific requirement that I'm struggling to fulfill. The API documentation states that when a user accesses the **link**, it creates a **copy in their personal account**, granting them full control over the copy to **share or edit**.

### Problem

The link of the Linking API generate a new report every time it's clicked and this report will be located in the user's workspace. Ideally, I needed to create a new report from a template and then give access to a "client group" and share this new report link with the clients.

### Paths

So far, I've imagined to use a dummy Gmail account to fake click in the Linking API using `puppeteer`, but this seems over complicated. The Looker Studio API don't seem to help, AFAIK, as it only deals with *search* and *permissions* (Permissions would be useful after creating the report from the template using `puppeteer`)

If anyone has any insights or suggestions to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your help.

[Linking API documentation from Looker Studio](https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/linking-api)

Answer (score 1):

When you create the link, ignore the .com/**embed**/x part and when you share the URL to them they will have the option to SAVE/EDIT the report.  AFAIK each click of the link may be a saved report in each persons looker space.  Simply clicking the link will only create a temporary view of the report with the supplied reporting parameters.

However if you do add the above to the url-slug you can supposedly embed in an iframe.  I myself have been getting permissions issues, or hiccups where some google auth cookie needs to be present, but that's another issue.

Honestly I have been working heavily with the Linking API over the past few weeks and would love some time to chat it out with another person.